.NET Maui Hybrid, Blazor Update UI mid method
I have a method that takes a few seconds to process. When a button is clicked I'd like it to update the UI to show processing, and then when the method has finished to change the UI. As an example, I have taken the boiler plate code and modified the counter click to the following:
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">@ButtonText</button>

@code {
private int currentCount = 0;

private string ButtonText = "Click";

private void IncrementCount()
{
    ButtonText = "Running";
    StateHasChanged();
    currentCount++;
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    ButtonText = "Click";
    StateHasChanged();
}
}

I clearly don't understand the thread processing or something. In the example, the button text does not change.
Running .NET 9 Maui Hybrid.


Thread.Sleep(1000);

This call suspends the current thread (in this case UI thread) for specified amount of time. It's the reason why button text is never updated to "Running". Cause the UI thread is suspended immediately by Thread.Sleep() before UI gets Updated.
If delaying execution for specific amount of time is your goal, then you should make the method asynchronous and await a Task.Delay() call like below.
 private async void IncrementCount()
 {
     ButtonText = "Running";
     StateHasChanged();
     currentCount++;
     await Task.Delay(1000);
     ButtonText = "Click";
     StateHasChanged();
 }

you can find more about Thread.Sleep() and Task.Delay() here
